# Video loader overrides the div element

Tags: reactjs

The video loader overrides the fixed bottom element, thus makes it quite unpleasant. I'am streaming the videos online and player used for it is React HLS player. What would be the best solution to prevent the overriding of loader. Following is the code reference

React HLS Player

```
       <ReactHlsPlayer
          url={video_url}
          autoplay={false}
           controls={true}
           width="100%"
           height="auto"
           config={{
           file: {
           forceHLS: true,
           }
          }}
        />
```

Bottom Navbar Code

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    width: "100%",
    bottom: "0px",
    position: "sticky"
  },
  gridList: {
    flexWrap: "nowrap",
    position: "fixed",
    bottom: "0px",
    background: "white",
    border: "1px solid grey",
    width: "100%"
  }
});

<GridList className={classes.gridList}>
      {itemList.map((tile, index) => {
        return (
          <GridListTile
            key={tile.icon}
            style={{ height: "70px", width: "25%" }}
          >
            <ListItem button key={tile.text}
              onClick={(tile.text == "DirectLine") ? directLineFunc : ''}
            >
              <NavLink
                exact
                to={tile.link}
                key={tile.key}
                activeClassName="main-nav-active"
                style={{ textAlign: "center" }}
                isActive={(match, location) => {
                  match && setNewActiveLink(index)
                  return match;
                }}
              >
                <ListItemText
                  disableTypography
                  primary={
                    <Typography
                      style={{
                        fontSize: "10px",
                        fontWeight: "bold",
                        fontFamily: "Nunito"
                      }}
                    >
                      {tile.text}
                    </Typography>
                  }
                />
              </NavLink>
            </ListItem>
          </GridListTile>
        );
      })}
    </GridList>
```

See the image below
[image]

And this the codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-material-forked-dtx6w

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to sort out by adding 'zIndex:999' to gridList of BottomNavbar with the following changes in useStyles as:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    width: "100%",
    bottom: "0px",
    position: "sticky"
  },
  gridList: {
    flexWrap: "nowrap",
    position: "fixed",
    bottom: "0px",
    background: "white",
    border: "1px solid grey",
    width: "100%",
    zIndex: 999 {/* <-- Here I added this and issue solved */}
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I added a `style={{marginBottom: "100px"}}` property in the `<ReactHlsPlayer />` and it seems to fix your problem

Comment: How will that do?

Comment: It creates space between the Stream Player and the navigation bar on the bottom of the page. So you have full access to the player. Wasn't this what you wanted?

Comment: No but, still that loader persists